# Stack with image & Textfield flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this design where the images i provide autoscroll everytime,it's working fine,but when i try to overlap with the textfield so the textfield should be in between of the image as Stacked ,i tried with stack,but the textfield doesn't move to top,there is the Screenshot what i am getting,please help me on this

This is what i am getting

[image: This is what i am getting]

Code

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 180,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Swiper(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return new Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/banner1.jpeg',
                      width: double.infinity,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 3,
                  pagination: new SwiperPagination(
                      margin: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 200, bottom: 20)),
                  control: new SwiperControl(),
                  autoplay: true,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 30, right: 30),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.orangeAccent[200], width: 4.0),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 110,
                      width: size.width,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100,
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: You only have one `Widget` in your `Stack`, a `Column`. If you want the elements that are inside your `Column` to stack on each other, you have to them from the `Column` to the `Stack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, TextField is inside COlumn that's why it appears below the image, you have to remove that code and add in stack list,

Example:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 180,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: new Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/image.jpg',
                      width: double.infinity,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 110,
                          width: 40,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: 10,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  color: Colors.yellow,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 150),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.orangeAccent[200], width: 4.0),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```